# Capture line-in audio, stream to vps and rebroadcast for mobile device

Tags: sound, streaming

I need do something like this:

Capture from line-in  ---stream---> vps ----stream---> 5-6 mobile devices

Now I using icecast with burts off as server on vps and darkice to capture audio on my local pc, but I got 6-15s delays and its for much for me :(

Could I get 0.2-2s latency with other software?
What software I should install on my local computer and on vps and how to configure it to works?

Answer (score 0):

In icecast.xml , reduce "burst size" to 0 will reduce the delay  .

Increasing bit rate will also reduce delay (256 kb/s better than 128).

You can also reduce buffer size in darkice.cfg (try .5 or 1 sec )